# Very low fps, except when running something else on background

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, ram

So, i give development support to a private server for a game called metin2.
The game have low requirements so it runs pretty smoothly, but there is a certain zone in the game that is going well and like randomly and instantly, the fps drops from 40 to 0,1, and it looks like a powerpoint presentation.

The solution the community has come up with (it was pure luck and coincidence) is running "counter strike 1.6" on the background (probably another game should also work) and the game runs smoothly.

So basically, my question is: How does consuming more CPU and RAM actually improves the fps performance in that zone of the game? The game processes are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Is the zone a high-load area and is this occuring for all users ?

Just because it reminds me of some solutions to frame spikes issues I've had before, which were related to some intel speedstep/C1M/turbo/something something BIOS CPU options. 
The short of it is that in some 3D applications at certain times when load was *low*, it'd be too low and whichever feature would determine that less performance was needed and underclock. This was some years ago now but maybe a worthwhile train of thought.